# mkdir through bash creates an unexpected temp name

Tags: bash, raspberry-pi, mkdir, samba

When I create a directory on a mounted samba share in ssh with this command:

```
mkdir -p /media/networkshare/public/backups/svr2/2016_03_15_15
```

Everything works as expected, but when I do it through bash:

```
#!/bin/bash
mkdir -p /media/networkshare/public/backups/svr2/2016_03_15_15
```

The directory is created with a temp name like: 2AD9UB~Q

Please help

Comment: I think this is a 'superuser' kind of post, not a stackoverflow one.

Answer (score 0):

This was caused by windows line endings.  I fixed it by running the file through [dos2unix](http://www.linuxcommand.org/man_pages/dos2unix1.html)